# Why does function finfo_file show the wrong mime type in codeigniter's upload class?

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, mime-types

I noticed that I get a "file type not allowed" error when trying to upload a regular txt document. I verified the mime type using the following command:

```
~ $ file --mime /home/user/Documents/New_Linux_Installation.txt
/home/user/Documents/New_Linux_Installation.txt: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

However, codeigniter's upload class gives me this mime type: text/x-lisp. Any idea why that could be? I'm using PHP 5.3.8. Here is the part of the code that generates the MIME type. I added the log_message part to show me the mime type:

```
protected function _file_mime_type($file)
    {
        // We'll need this to validate the MIME info string (e.g. text/plain; charset=us-ascii)
        $regexp = '/^([a-z\-]+\/[a-z0-9\-\.\+]+)(;\s.+)?$/';

        /* Fileinfo extension - most reliable method
         *
         * Unfortunately, prior to PHP 5.3 - it's only available as a PECL extension and the
         * more convenient FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE flag doesn't exist.
         */
        if (function_exists('finfo_file'))
        {
            $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);

            if (is_resource($finfo)) // It is possible that a FALSE value is returned, if there is no magic MIME database file found on the system
            {
                $mime = @finfo_file($finfo, $file['tmp_name']);
                finfo_close($finfo);

                log_message('error', 'mime: '.var_export($mime, TRUE), '', 'debug');

                /* According to the comments section of the PHP manual page,
                 * it is possible that this function returns an empty string
                 * for some files (e.g. if they don't exist in the magic MIME database)
                 */
                if (is_string($mime) && preg_match($regexp, $mime, $matches))
                {
                    $this->file_type = $matches[1];
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

What's interesting is that the original file upload info does show the correct mime type. I'm talking specifically about the $_FILES['filename']['type'] variable. It's during codeigniter's processing that it changes it to the wrong one.

Comment: Is your application running on a different machine than where you ran the `file` command?

Comment: Nope, same machine. I'm running on localhost, using Linux.

Comment: It seems like `file` and `finfo_file` are using two different magic databases. `$_FILES['filename']['type']` is set by the client is generally not reliable.

Comment: There must be something inside the file that makes `finfo_open` believe  it's a lisp file. `finfo_*` utilizes an OS-level library that uses telltale signs (header bytes, key words) to recognize file formats. The original mime type is determined by the client browser (or rather, usually probably the underlying OS); its being different from the server-side result is not unexpected.

Comment: ...what can you do? The problem is likely to be in the mime magic file that is being used by fileinfo. You can [specify a custom mime magic file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php) when calling the function, but I'm not sure what it would have to look like so errors like this can be completely excluded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did find out exactly why it was showing the wrong MIME type, but in case anyone else is having the same problem, I ended up extending the upload class, copying the `_file_mime_type` function, and disabling the `if (function_exists('finfo_file'))` statement in order to make it move on to the next method of obtaining the mime type.